# Tabulator and send data to C#

Tags: tabulator

When using tabulator-tables@4.9.3
Created 2 drop down list columns with editor: "select"
Used Code:

```
{title: "ProductID", field: "productID", sorter: "string", minWidth: 100, width: 150, sorter: "number", editable: Editable, editor: "number", validator: "required", hozAlign: "left", editor: "select", editorParams: { values: ProductIDSelect }, formatter: "lookup" , formatterParams: ProductIDSelect },
```

For Example: Products and Units. This type of drop down contain Name, ID.
After choose the name and press on save button will send the data from tabulator to C# to check all data type and Inserted to the table in database Image below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Utm3z.png)

Before sanded data I check data array with press right click on the page choose "Inspect" getting the below image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9a8J.png)

Shares indicate the number between "4" and "5" string type

When matching data by C# and finds that the Integer field type and string data are incorrect

Comment: Without seeing the relevant code it's impossible to give an answer, but at least there must be "some" form of type conversion. Numbers can never be equal (or even compared to) strings.

Comment: I sent a question with more details. Question name is : Save Data by Tabulator